# How to Sum an Array element-wise, in reverse?

Tags: c++, arrays

The issue i'm having is I have an array of ones, such that:

```
double foo[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

And what i'm trying to do is take foo[4] and keep that as it's original value, and then sum each in reverse. The end result would have a new matrix, called foosum, that looks like this:

foosum[5] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

The last line isn't in code cause it is the result i'm trying to reach, and not necessarily code in. I'd tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
     double foo[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
     double foosum[sizeof(foosum)];
     int len = sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]);
     
     for (int i = (len - 1); i >=0; --i) {
          s[i] = 0;
          for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
               s[len - i] += foosum[j];
          }
     }
     std::copy(foosum, foosum + len,
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
     return 0;
}
```

The language is cpp, the double for loop was my attempt to go through the foo array and then sum it in reverse, per the problem i'm trying to resolve. There is an error in that for loop with s, which is that it can't be resolved. The index may also be slightly off. I'm new to cpp, and while it is similar to python, which i'm intermediate in, it is a different type of beast for me.

The std::copy set is my copy of the array in order to print it out.

This problem is a personal one that i'd like to figure out how to solve to set a good foundation for future stuff. Please let me know if you have questions!

Thanks.

Comment: *"error in that for loop with s, which is that it can't be resolved"* Well yep, you didn't create any variables named `s`. Also, this doesn't look right: `double foosum[sizeof(foosum)];` It shouldn't compile.

Comment: `double foosum[sizeof(foosum)];` is looking a wee bit Zen. In order to determine the size of `foosum`, you must first determine the size of `foosum`.

Comment: Yes, it's in the wrong spot and utilizing the wrong variable I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) which you can use like this:

```
std::partial_sum(std::rbegin(foo), std::rend(foo), std::rbegin(foosum));
```

Also, note that `sizeof(foo)` is not going to do what you want. Just do:

```
double foosum[std::size(foo)];
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j6vzEc).

Comment: Oh okay, I wasn't aware that partial_sum existed. And yes, after I figured out the question, I remembered the whole thing about sizeof() dealing with bytes rather than elements, and that I had that in the wrong place. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, keeping it closer to OP's attempt.

```
     double foo[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
     const int len = sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]);
     double foosum[len];
     
     foosum[len - 1] = foo[len - 1];
     for (int i = len - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
          foosum[i] = foo[i] + foosum[i + 1];
     }
```